# AngularComponent with @inject how to test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have the following component in Angular with the following constructor

```
  constructor(@Inject('CustomersServiceImp') public customerService: CustomersService,
   ) { }
```

How do I inject the `CustomersServiceImp` when configuring the testing module.  On top of that `CustomersService` is an interface and not a concrete class.  I tried the following without any success

```
  const customersServiceToken = new InjectionToken<CustomersService>(
    "CustomersServiceImp"
  );

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
   Comp
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [{ provide: customersServiceToken, useValue: {} }],
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: I figured if I put the following in the component itself `  const customersServiceToken = new InjectionToken<CustomersService>(
    "CustomersServiceImp"
  );` and then import it, then it works, however if I put the same code in the spec.ts file it does not work, I'm not sure why this is the case, any ideas anyone ?